# alteryx workflow with python script

Tags: python, automation, alteryx

i have 2 python scripts which does excel automation task i need to use alteryx automation workflow including 2 python scripts, 1 python script is responsible for data preparation in excel and another script is reponsible to filling out the data from other excel file in to data preparation file created by 1st python script.

i tried taking excel file for which data preparation task to be done and populate it to python script with the help of command tool it is giving out the result as expected but i am unable to input the output of 1st python script and 2nd excel where data needs to be filled

i have 2nd python script ready it is able to perform the operation as well but have no idea how to do it with alteryx

any idea or help is greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.